# How to get attributes for all intersecting polygons after using `st_intersection(x)`?

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to create a dataset that has non intersecting polygons and their attributes as well as the attributes of both/all polygons when they do intersect.

to demo the problem I create some made up data

```
set.seed(131)
library(sf)

#create example data
m = rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))
p = st_polygon(list(m))
n = 20
l = vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n)
  l[[i]] = p + 10 * runif(2)
s = st_sfc(l)
plot(s, col = sf.colors(categorical = TRUE, alpha = .5))
title("overlapping squares")

#convert to sf object
s <- st_as_sf(s)

#add some random info
s$tree_type <- rep(c("oak", "pine", "fir"), length.out=nrow(s))
```

which looks like this
[image]

And the data looks like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 20 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.3840939 ymin: 1.132567 xmax: 10.19807 ymax: 10.14945
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
                                x tree_type
1  POLYGON ((2.06437 1.249422,...       oak
2  POLYGON ((2.932732 3.757797...      pine
3  POLYGON ((8.463468 5.292048...       fir
4  POLYGON ((5.186254 2.378545...       oak
5  POLYGON ((3.263181 9.149452...      pine
6  POLYGON ((4.162483 3.446414...       fir
7  POLYGON ((8.651544 3.160404...       oak
8  POLYGON ((5.231186 2.916041...      pine
9  POLYGON ((0.3840939 6.87075...       fir
10 POLYGON ((7.742229 4.721718...       oak
```

Then I do a self intersection like so

```
s_intersection <- st_intersection(s)
```

which creates data like this

```
Simple feature collection with 31 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.3840939 ymin: 1.132567 xmax: 10.19807 ymax: 10.14945
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
    tree_type n.overlaps origins                              x
1         oak          1       1 POLYGON ((2.06437 1.249422,...
2        pine          1       2 POLYGON ((3.932732 4.757797...
3         fir          1       3 POLYGON ((8.463468 6.292048...
4         oak          1       4 POLYGON ((6.186254 2.378545...
5        pine          1       5 POLYGON ((3.263181 9.149452...
6         fir          1       6 POLYGON ((4.162483 3.446414...
7         oak          1       7 POLYGON ((9.651544 3.160404...
4.1       oak          2    4, 8 POLYGON ((6.186254 2.916041...
8        pine          1       8 MULTIPOLYGON (((5.826989 3....
9         fir          1       9 POLYGON ((0.3840939 6.87075...
```

What I want to do is replace the column `origins` with attributes from both polygons. So for example polygon 4.1 would become `oak, pine`. Or it is fine if it is in two columns. The way I am thinking about approaching this problem is to unlist observations in the `origins` column so that each value is in its own column, then bind the attributes of the polygons to each value in the multiple `origins` columns. But is there an easier way?

Comment: As people rarely give compliments on stackoverflow: great job creating a reproducible example! I hope someone can help you!

Comment: The edited accepted solution now handles all attribute columns of the original spatial dataframe, not only a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possibility, using {dplyr} for convenience:

**edit**
a generalized solution for more than one attribute column:

- add some attributes and re-intersect:

```
s$temperature <- rep(c("low", "medium", "high"), length.out=nrow(s))
s$region = rep(c("Oak county", "Pine state", "Fir territory"), length.out=nrow(s))

s_intersection <- st_intersection(s)
```

- add attributes as comma-separated string (skip if fine with list-column):

```
 s_intersection |>
 rowwise() |>
 mutate(across(-c(x, origins), ## leave out x (geometry col) and origins
               ~ list(as.data.frame(s)[origins, cur_column()]) |>
                 unlist() |> paste(collapse = ', ')
               )
        )
```

```
Simple feature collection with 31 features and 5 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.3840939 ymin: 1.132567 xmax: 10.19807 ymax: 10.14945
CRS:           NA
# A tibble: 31 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   tree_type temperature region     n.overlaps origins                         x
 * <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <list>                 <GEOMETRY>
 1 oak       low         Oak county ""         <int>   POLYGON ((2.06437 1.2494~
# ...
 8 oak, pine low, medium Oak count~ ""         <int>   POLYGON ((6.186254 2.916~
# ...
```

Or, if you want to replicate polygons into one row per tree type, `separate_rows` from {tidyr} might be handy.

Answer (score 3):

```r
st_join(s, s, st_intersects)
```

```
Simple feature collection with 42 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.3840939 ymin: 1.132567 xmax: 10.19807 ymax: 10.14945
CRS:           NA
First 10 features:
    tree_type.x tree_type.y                              x
1           oak         oak POLYGON ((2.06437 1.249422,...
2          pine        pine POLYGON ((2.932732 3.757797...
2.1        pine         oak POLYGON ((2.932732 3.757797...
3           fir         fir POLYGON ((8.463468 5.292048...
3.1         fir         oak POLYGON ((8.463468 5.292048...
4           oak         oak POLYGON ((5.186254 2.378545...
4.1         oak        pine POLYGON ((5.186254 2.378545...
4.2         oak         oak POLYGON ((5.186254 2.378545...
5          pine        pine POLYGON ((3.263181 9.149452...
6           fir         fir POLYGON ((4.162483 3.446414...
```

You were on the right track with self-intersection, but you need to fully cross the original geometry with itself, so you can do a join with `st_intersects` to accomplish that.